# Java order list of objects by null fields

Tags: java, sorting, collections, null, comparator

I have a list of objects, for example students. A student has a first, middle and last name. `

Lets say for purpose of this example each field can be null. I would like to order the list so that all null fields are move to end of the list and all non nulls at the top.

I do not need to order based the actual non null values.

Example:

```
[
    Harry, John, Carter,
    Tony, Thomas, Holmes,
    John, null, Chavez,
    null, Micharl, Heinz,
    null, null, Simpson,
    null, null, null
]
```

Is it possible to have a single comparator to achieve this or do I need separate ones ?

Comment: I hope that your teacher assigned the first, middle, and last-name thing. Real names are much more complex than that.

Comment: So you want to dissolve the `Student` objects into their fields, to move the `null` fields at the end of the list, to have a bunch of meaningless `null` values at the end? Or do you want to sort a list of students, to move students *with* null fields to the end? Then, what happens to students with some null fields and some non-null fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which takes all the info of a student and determine priority based on info and return priority value.

- If all field not-null - priority value 1
- If all field null - priority value 3
- Else for other case - priority value 2

Then sort by priority value using a comparator

```
studentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> getPriority(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava (Google's Java core library):

```
List<Integer> toSort = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 4, null, 1, 2);
Collections.sort(toSort, Ordering.natural().nullsLast()); // sorting nulls last
assertThat(toSort.get(toSort.size() - 1), nullValue());
```

Read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-order).